# UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey doesn't work with custom keyboard in ios8

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios8

the UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey always return when used on a device with a custom keyboard installed.

when I run my code on all ios 7 or 8 that doesn't have custom keyboard everything works

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine with UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey.